# Register member using facebook through cartThrob or Expressionengine

Tags: php, facebook, expressionengine, cartthrob

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd like new customers to be able to create an account on our website (expressionengine and cartthrob) by just clicking the "login with facebook" type of button.  Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Facebook Connect](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/facebook_connect/) from Solspace?  I have not used it myself but thought it looked interesting and have had good experiences with other Solspace products.